# How is Booster Gold part of the Justice League?

Tags: dc, booster-gold

Booster Gold is an admitted thief, was expelled from Gotham City University, and all he's after is fame and glory because he was kind of a loser in the 25th century.

Why would the other Leaguemates allow him to join?

Comment: @Thaddeus I don't understand why you felt the need to change my question. It was fine enough the way it was and you deleted details I wanted to be kept in the question.

Comment: The real question should be "How does the Justice League allow a time traveler from the future to have an impact on the timeline of the present?" The amount of changes that Booster Gold could theoretically introduce to the timeline is kind of frightening.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### [Booster Gold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booster_gold) is summed up in the opening lines of his Wikipedia entry:

> Booster Gold is a fictional DC Comics superhero. Created by Dan
> Jurgens, he first appeared in Booster Gold #1 (February 1986) and has
> been a member of the Justice League, DC Comics' all-star team of
> heroes. The character is initially depicted as a glory-seeking
> showboat from the future, using knowledge of historical events and
> futuristic technology to stage high-publicity heroics. Booster
> develops over the course of his publication history and through
> personal tragedies to become a true hero weighed down by the
> reputation he has created for himself.

[image]

Booster Gold was labeled "The Best New Hero You Never Heard Of." The intent of the hero was to question what makes a hero, technology, ability, or upbringing. The character of Booster Gold has suffered significant change from its initial development so it isn't hard to question how he could end up being a member of the Justice League in any form. If your exposure to the character is from Smallville, your opinion of him might be even worse.

Being a thief or a wrong-doer is does not immediately disqualify a hero from being a member of the Justice League. Several of their members have had questionable run-ins with the law or have fought against the legal system.

- **Batman:** Considered a vigilante by Gotham City in several iterations
  of the DC Universe
- **Plastic Man:** reformed criminal mobster after his
  transformation into his mutable self
- **Red Tornado:** created by Professor Ivo (super-villain) to attack and destroy the Justice League
- **Superman:** Even the perfect Superman has in several iterations of the DCU, has tried to take over the world
- **The Question:** Wanted by the law regarding incidents in his home city.
- **Green Arrow:** In the previous DCU kills with the help of the Shade, the murderer Prometheus.

The real issue for the Justice League is more one of evolving character. Booster Gold did start off with a questionable pedigree for a hero, and his return to the past, using his future knowledge did not bode well. He, through trial and error, support from other heroes, guidance from his AI Skeets, personal tragedies, including the death of his closest friend Ted Kord, the Blue Beetle, began to show the real character of a man who wanted to and could become a real hero.

Nor is the history of the [Justice League](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justice_League) as perfect as we would like to believe. It has also had some questionable behaviors in some if its iterations. The Justice League is a brand name and sometimes the brand suffered depending on who was a member of the line-up at the time.

[Booster Gold's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booster_gold) induction to the Justice League International in the previous DCU was eventually something he grew to fit. If you want to see how many different changes the character has been through, you need to read through his Wikipedia entry.

---

I read the adventures of Booster Gold both when he had his own book and almost all of his appearances in the JLI comics for many years trying to see DC was working so hard to make the hero successful. If you haven't had the pleasure, he and the Blue Beetle made the Justice League International the hit that it was. Humor can sell comics.

I realized, probably the same way DC did, they needed to try harder to bring new heroes into the fold. Recycling their universes without adding new heroes would eventually fail their industry. Booster Gold is an example of that ideal. While my love of the character has not grown, my respect for what has been done to make him a better and more respectable hero has grown significantly.

His pedigree in the new DCnU and whether he will make the cut for the League is still anyone's guess.

Comment: +1. I was writing an answer and you've ninja'd me, but this is an excellent answer. :)

Comment: Sorry about that. I love comics and while Booster wasn't one of my favorites, I thought I would share what I knew.

Comment: No problem, your write-up is more detailed than the one I was composing.